# Number of different lines in each file - Compare all files inside 2 directories

Tags: perl, unix, compare

I have 2 directories dir1 and dir2 with thousand of files. I have a perl script to compare these two and print the difference in a different file.
I am using the diff my $diff = `diff -y --suppress-common-lines "$DirA/$file" "$DirB/$file"`; to compare all files(with same name) in the two directories. With this, I also want to add

Filename:   # of different lines

File 1 – 1

File 2  - 30

and output the difference in a summary.txt file . 
Can someone please help me with the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
echo $file - `diff -y --suppress-common-lines $DirA/$file $DirB/$file | wc -l` >> summary.txt
```

Comment: Above line works fine on the prompt but when I add the same in my script, system("echo $file - `diff -y --suppress-common-lines $DirA/$file $DirB/$file | wc -l` >> summary.txt"); I get this error Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at test_switch.tc line 109, <> line 1. Which means I have not initialized $file. What do I initialize it to? Initializing to zero gives a wrong output